# How to simulate click on button Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using the package webview_flutter. How can I simulate a button click? I tried using the controller to run some javascript:

```
controller.evaluateJavascript("$('.mybuttonclass').click()")
```

Unfortunately It seems we cannot use JQuery here as I received a '$ not found error'. Is there a possible workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById("myButtonId").click()
```

Or `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: And how do I click on getElementsByClassName? There's no click there!